# Aplicación de chat para python

Tags: python, flask

He seguido el tutorial de [esta](https://codeburst.io/building-your-first-chat-application-using-flask-in-7-minutes-f98de4adfa5d) página y he logrado correr el servidor para chat que se especifica, pero me encuentro con un problema:

**No admite la entrada de texto con caracteres especiales como la ñ, á,Ó...**

alguién sabe de qué agregar al código para lograr obtener estos caracteres al chat?

[image: imagen de muestra]

El codigo es:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO    
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'vnkdjnfjknfl1232#'
socketio = SocketIO(app)    
@app.route('/')
def sessions():
    return render_template('session.html')    
def messageReceived(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('message was received!!!')

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('received my event: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('my response', json, callback=messageReceived)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True,host='0.0.0.0', port=1234)
```

y el archivo plantilla que carga es

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es">
  <head>
    <title>Flask_Chat_App</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<h3 style='color: #ccc;font-size: 30px;'>Bienvenidos..</h3>
<div class="message_holder"></div>

<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" class="username" placeholder="Nombre"/>
  <input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Mensaje"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
  socket.on( 'connect', function() {
    socket.emit( 'my event', {
      data: 'User Connected'
    } )
    var form = $( 'form' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
      e.preventDefault()
      let user_name = $( 'input.username' ).val()
      let user_input = $( 'input.message' ).val()
      socket.emit( 'my event', {
        user_name : user_name,
        message : user_input
      } )
      $( 'input.message' ).val( '' ).focus()
    } )
  } )
  socket.on( 'my response', function( msg ) {
    console.log( msg )
    if( typeof msg.user_name !== 'undefined' ) {
      $( 'h3' ).remove()
      $( 'div.message_holder' ).append( '<div><b style="color: #000">'+msg.user_name+'</b> '+msg.message+'</div>' )
    }
  })
</script>
```

intenté cambiar la segunda línea que dice `<html lang="en">` a `<html lang="es">` pero no me resultó. ¿será que acaso debo pasar a utf8 la entrada de texto o crear un diccionario para reemplazar cada combinación de texto en el caracter corecto?

Comment: Puedes usar un replace con el texto que vas a mandar, y pasarlo a HTML ASCII (por ejemplo ú sería `&#250;`) mapear el caracter y su equivalente en HTML a un diccionario: https://www.ascii.cl/es/codigos-html.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a cambiar en tu plantilla:

```
  socket.emit( 'my event', {
    user_name : user_name,
    message : user_input
  } )
```

Por esto:

```
  socket.emit( 'my event', {
    user_name : encodeURIComponent(user_name),
    message : encodeURIComponent(user_input)
  } )
```

Y esto:

```
  $( 'div.message_holder' ).append( '<div><b style="color: #000">'+msg.user_name+'</b> '+msg.message+'</div>' )
```

Por esto:

```
  $( 'div.message_holder' ).append( '<div><b style="color: #000">'+decodeURIComponent(msg.user_name)+'</b> '+decodeURIComponent(msg.message)+'</div>' )
```

Por lo que he leido, socket.emit da muchos problemas con los caracteres especiales.

Answer (score 2):

Esos problemas de codificacion resultan cuando el template HTML intenta renderizar carácteres Unicode (UTF8) como ANSI.

La solución consiste en avisar al renderizador HTML que el texto está en Unicode, y esto se logra utilizando el *div* `meta` en `head` del `html`. En tu caso, prueba agregando el siguiente codigo al `head` del *template*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="es">
  <head>
   <title>Flask_Chat_App</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
 <!-- etc ... -->
```

Comment: te funciona? porque a mi no :(

Comment: Prueba con  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> 

Esto funciona ocupando html5. también puedes probar 
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"> 
o
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">

Comment: ninguno ha resuelto el problema. también intente cambiando esto dos lineas debajo del body `<form action="" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: Que versión de python y flask estas ocupando?

Comment: python 3.7.3 y flask 1.0.2, pero los titulos sí aceptan los caracteres especiales. El problema es que el texto que se introduce en `Mensaje` no se convierte a utf8

Answer (score 1):

Importa make_response en la primera línea.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response
```

Después en la función de sessions(), sé explícito en la respuesta, diciéndole el charset específico en el que funcionará tu html/chat.

```
def sessions():
    response = make_response(render_template('session.html'))
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
    return response
```

En mi experiencia enviar el charset desde el servidor me ha resultado más efectivo que ponerlo en los meta, ya que me he estrellado muchas veces con que no quieren funcionar estos en repetidas ocasiones.